# How to provide alignment to chunk or phrases in itext?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have two chunks, added in phrases and then in paragraph.

```
Chunk reportTitle= new Chunk("Candidate Login Report ",catFont);
Chunk divisiontitle = new Chunk("Division : \t\t"+divisionName);

Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(reportTitle);
phrase.add(divisiontitle);

Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.add(phrase);
```

I have to set chunk `divisiontitle` to right aligned. Is there any provision to do this in iIext?

Comment: I know the method of paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT) but there is no such method for chunk or phrases.

Comment: That comment shows that you're trying to solve the problem yourself. It's appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a `Chunk` for `divisiontitle` instead of a `Paragraph`? "All other layout parameters should be defined in the object to which this chunk of text is added."

Comment: if i take different paragraphs instead of chunk then it will print into two different lines.i have to keep both divisiontitle and report title text on same line. and have to set alignment of divisiontitle to right aligned.

Comment: Wouldn't a table with no borders be better then? One row, two columns, the left one containing `reportTitle` left aligned, and the right one containing `divisionTitle` and right aligned.

Comment: yes,it may be a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the word processors since WordPerfect seem to have dropped the "flush right" command, and iText doesn't seem to have one either. The usual solution for word processing is to make two columns and justify them separately, so also I think that approach is probably the most practical here.

Comment: The "flush right" command can be mimicked by introducing a separator `Chunk`.

Answer (score 9):

You really answered yourself in your comment.

```
Chunk reportTitle= new Chunk("Candidate Login Report ",catFont);
Chunk divisiontitle = new Chunk("Division : \t\t"+divisionName);

Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(reportTitle);
phrase.add(divisiontitle);

Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.add(phrase);
para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Then you can add it to any cell and it will be correctly aligned.

Answer (score 4):

bajrangi,

You might want to use ColumnText.showTextAligned() to align your text. Try the following:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, phrase, xPosition, yPosition, 0);
```

Cheers!

-Eric

Answer (score 3):

```
add multiple Chunk and Phrase in itextpdf
package com.pdf.hl;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class GraphicsStateOperators {

    public static final String RESULT = "d:/graphics_state.pdf";
    static Font.FontFamily ff = Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA;
    static float size = 10;
    static float size1 = 8;

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws Exception {
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////
        PdfPTable tabletmp = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabletmp.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        tabletmp.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        float[] colWidths = { 45, 55 };
        table.setWidths(colWidths);
        String imageUrl = "http://logo.com/content1/images/logo_heartSmart.jpg";
        Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
        image2.setWidthPercentage(60);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.addElement(image2);
        table.addCell(cell);
        String receiptNo = "123455555555555555";
        String collectionDate = "09/09/09";
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("Date: ", normal);
        Phrase ph1 = new Phrase(chunk1);

        Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(collectionDate, bold);
        Phrase ph2 = new Phrase(chunk2);

        Chunk chunk3 = new Chunk("\nReceipt No: ", normal);
        Phrase ph3 = new Phrase(chunk3);

        Chunk chunk4 = new Chunk(receiptNo, bold);
        Phrase ph4 = new Phrase(chunk4);

        Paragraph ph = new Paragraph();
        ph.add(ph1);
        ph.add(ph2);
        ph.add(ph3);
        ph.add(ph4);

        table.addCell(ph);
        tabletmp.addCell(table);
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setLineWidth((float) 10 / 10);
        canvas.moveTo(40, 806 - (5 * 10));
        canvas.lineTo(555, 806 - (5 * 10));
        canvas.stroke();
        document.add(tabletmp);
        canvas.restoreState();
        PdfPTable tabletmp1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabletmp1.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        tabletmp1.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        float[] colWidths1 = { 60, 40 };
        table1.setWidths(colWidths1);
        String Patient = "abcddd";
        String Email = "test@test.com";
        String Phone = "89890099890890";
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
        cell3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        Chunk chunkPatientLabal = new Chunk("Patient: ", normal);
        Phrase phPatientLabal = new Phrase(chunkPatientLabal);
        Chunk chunkPatient = new Chunk(Patient, bold);
        Phrase phPatient = new Phrase(chunkPatient);
        Chunk chunkEmailLabal = new Chunk("\nEmail: ", normal);
        Phrase phEmailLabal = new Phrase(chunkEmailLabal);
        Chunk chunkEmail = new Chunk(Email, bold);
        Phrase phEmail = new Phrase(chunkEmail);
        Chunk chunkPhoneLabal = new Chunk("\nPhone: ", normal);
        Phrase phPhoneLabal = new Phrase(chunkPhoneLabal);
        Chunk chunkPhone = new Chunk(Phone, bold);
        Phrase phPhone = new Phrase(chunkPhone);
        Paragraph phN = new Paragraph();
        phN.add(phPatientLabal);
        phN.add(phPatient);
        phN.add(phEmailLabal);
        phN.add(phEmail);
        phN.add(phPhoneLabal);
        phN.add(phPhone);
        cell3.addElement(phN);
        table1.addCell(cell3);
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
        cell4.getBorderWidthRight();
        cell4.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        String ReferingPhysician = "phy Patient";
        Chunk chunkRefPhyLabal = new Chunk("Refering Physician: ", normal);
        Phrase phRefPhyLabal = new Phrase(chunkRefPhyLabal);
        Chunk chunkRefPhy = new Chunk(ReferingPhysician, bold);
        Phrase phRefPhy = new Phrase(chunkRefPhy);
        Paragraph phN1 = new Paragraph();
        phN1.add(phRefPhyLabal);
        phN1.setAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        phN1.add(phRefPhy);
        cell4.addElement(phN1);
        table1.addCell(cell4);
        tabletmp1.addCell(table1);
        tabletmp1.setSpacingAfter(10);
        document.add(tabletmp1);
        PdfPTable table7 = new PdfPTable(1);
        table7.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell c7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Payment Summry", new Font(ff,
                size, Font.BOLD)));
        BaseColor headingColor7 = WebColors.getRGBColor("#989898");
        c7.setBackgroundColor(headingColor7);
        c7.setHorizontalAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table7.addCell(c7);
        table7.setSpacingAfter(2f);
        document.add(table7);
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        PdfPTable tabletmp2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        BaseColor headingColor8 = WebColors.getRGBColor("#F0F0F0");
        tabletmp2.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPTable table8 = new PdfPTable(2);
        table8.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table8.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        table8.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        float[] colWidths8 = { 50, 50 };
        table8.setWidths(colWidths8);
        PdfPCell cellPaymentSummry = new PdfPCell();
        cellPaymentSummry.setBackgroundColor(headingColor8);
        cellPaymentSummry.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        Chunk chunkPaymentInvoiceLabal = new Chunk("Invoice Id", normal);
        Phrase phPaymentInvoiceLabal = new Phrase(chunkPaymentInvoiceLabal);

        Chunk chunkPaymentModeLabal = new Chunk("\nPayment Mode", normal);
        Phrase phPaymentModeLabal = new Phrase(chunkPaymentModeLabal);
        Chunk chunkAmountReceivedLabal = new Chunk("\nAmount Received", normal);
        Chunk chunkAmountDueLabal = new Chunk("\nAmount Due", normal);
        Phrase phAmountDueLabal = new Phrase(chunkAmountDueLabal);

        Phrase phAmountReceivedLabal = new Phrase(chunkAmountReceivedLabal);
        Paragraph phPaymentSummry = new Paragraph();
        phPaymentSummry.add(phPaymentInvoiceLabal);
        phPaymentSummry.add(phPaymentModeLabal);
        phPaymentSummry.add(phAmountReceivedLabal);
        phPaymentSummry.add(phAmountDueLabal);
        cellPaymentSummry.addElement(phPaymentSummry);
        table8.addCell(cellPaymentSummry);

        PdfPCell cellPaymentSummry1 = new PdfPCell();
        cellPaymentSummry1.setBackgroundColor(headingColor8);
        cellPaymentSummry1.getBorderWidthRight();
        cellPaymentSummry1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        String PaymentMode = "rannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn";
        String amountReceived = "2.33";
        String amountDue = "28.00";
        String invoice = "123";

        Chunk chunkPaymentInvoicel = new Chunk(invoice, bold);
        Phrase phPaymentInvoice = new Phrase(chunkPaymentInvoicel);

        Chunk chunkPaymentMode = new Chunk("\n" + PaymentMode, bold);
        Phrase phPaymentMode = new Phrase(chunkPaymentMode);

        Chunk chunkAmountReceived = new Chunk("\n$" + amountReceived, bold);
        Phrase phAmountReceived = new Phrase(chunkAmountReceived);

        Chunk chunkAmountDue = new Chunk("\n$" + amountDue, bold);
        Phrase phAmountDue = new Phrase(chunkAmountDue);

        Paragraph phPaymentSummry1 = new Paragraph();
        phPaymentSummry1.add(phPaymentInvoice);
        phPaymentSummry1.add(phPaymentMode);
        phPaymentSummry1.setAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        phPaymentSummry1.add(phAmountReceived);

        phPaymentSummry1.add(phAmountDue);
        cellPaymentSummry1.addElement(phPaymentSummry1);
        table8.addCell(cellPaymentSummry1);
        tabletmp2.addCell(table8);
        document.add(tabletmp2);
        document.close();

    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GraphicsStateOperators().createPdf(RESULT);
        System.out.println("Done Please check........");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644620:

```
Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark())
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add("Text to the left");
p.Add(glue);
p.Add("Text to the right");
```

tested as working under iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.4.5 (iText 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet")

public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String RESOURCE = "images/logo-new.png";


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            PdfWriter writer = null;

            try {
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
                document.open();

                document.add(createHeaderTable());
                document.add(comapnyNameTable());
                document.add(createAddressTable());
                document.add(getTable());
                document.add(createFooterTable());

                PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
                canvas.setLineWidth((float) 10 / 10);
                canvas.moveTo(40,  765 - (5 * 10));
                canvas.lineTo(570, 770 - (5 * 10));
                canvas.stroke();

                document.close();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private PdfPTable createHeaderTable(){
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        try{
           table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
           table.setHorizontalAlignment(0);;
           table.setSpacingBefore(10);

           table.setWidths(new int[]{2, 6});
           Image img = Image.getInstance(RESOURCE);
           img.scalePercent(28f);

           PdfPCell pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(img,true);
           //pdfPCell.addElement(img);
           pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
           pdfPCell.setFixedHeight(50);
           table.addCell(pdfPCell);

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("Date:",bold));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("11-09-2015",normal));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("\nOrder Id:",bold));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("OrderId#12345",normal));
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(260);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph,50));
        }
        catch (DocumentException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return table;
    }

    private PdfPTable createAddressTable(){
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);

        try{
            table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
            table.setHorizontalAlignment(0);;
            table.setSpacingBefore(10);
            table.setSpacingAfter(10);

            table.setWidths(new int[]{2, 6});

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("Billed To",bold));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("\nOrdered By tdhdghfjghjg fvgfdghgfhg gfhggjdjh ghgfhgjhgjhg gfhghjghj dghgfh ghggfhgfh ghgffgh ghjggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg", normal));
            paragraph.setIndentationRight(40);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph,60));

            Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph2.add(new Chunk("Service By ",bold));
            paragraph2.add(new Chunk("\nService B gfdsgfdhghhhhy  tdhdghfjghjg fvgfdghgfhg gfhggjdjh ghgfhgjhgjhg gfhghjghj dghgfhh ghfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",normal));
            paragraph2.setIndentationLeft(260);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph2,60));

            Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph3.add(new Chunk("Payment Method:", bold));
            paragraph3.add(new Chunk("\nVisa ending with *888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888**********123,\nseeenu@gmail.com",normal));
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph3,60));

            Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph4.add(new Chunk("Order Date:",bold));
            paragraph4.add(new Chunk("\nMarch 7,2014",normal));
            paragraph4.setIndentationLeft(260);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph4,60));
        }
        catch (DocumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return table;
    }

    private PdfPTable comapnyNameTable(){
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);

        try{
            table.setWidthPercentage(100f);

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("Travels Company",bold));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("\nOrdered By tdhdghfjghjg fvgfdghgfhg gfhggjdjh ghgfhgjhgjhg gfhghjghj dghgfh ghggfhgfh ghgffgh ghjggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",normal));
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(200f);
            paragraph.setIndentationRight(200f);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph,60));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return table;
    }

    private PdfPTable createFooterTable(){
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);

        try{
            table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
            table.setHorizontalAlignment(0);;
            table.setSpacingBefore(10);
            table.setSpacingAfter(10);

            table.setWidths(new int[]{2, 6});
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("Tearms & Conditions",bold));
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("\ngfdhgfhgfh",normal));

            Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(10);
            paragraph2.add(new Chunk("Aggrigate Service By",bold));
            paragraph2.add(new Chunk("\nTruckWay",normal));
            paragraph2.setIndentationLeft(260);
            table.addCell(newPdfPcel(paragraph2,0));
        }
        catch (DocumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return table;
    }

    private Paragraph createParagraph(String text,Font font,float indentationLeft,float indentationRight){
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(10);
        paragraph.add(new Chunk(text,font));
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(indentationLeft);
        paragraph.setIndentationRight(indentationRight);
        return paragraph;
    }

    private PdfPCell newPdfPcel(Paragraph paragraph,float fixedHight){
        PdfPCell pdfPCell = new PdfPCell();
        pdfPCell.addElement(paragraph);
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPCell.setFixedHeight(fixedHight);
        return pdfPCell;
    }

    public PdfPTable getTable()throws DocumentException, IOException {
        // Create a table with 7 columns
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);

        // Add the first header row
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order Details", FontFactory.getFont("Arial",10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.setColspan(7);
        table.addCell(cell);
        Font font = new Font();
        font.setSize(10);
        font.setFamily("Arial");

        table.addCell(createCel("From Place",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Hyderabad",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("To Place",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Bangolore",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Truck RequestDate",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("09/9/15",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Truck Type",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("6 wheeler",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("No OfTrucks",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("1",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Total Capacity",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("8",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Total Amount",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("1000.00",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("From Addressy",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("hyd",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("To Address",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Bang",font,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Advance",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
        table.addCell(createCel("1000.00",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Service Charges",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
        table.addCell(createCel("25.00",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
        table.addCell(createCel("Total",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
        table.addCell(createCel("1000.25",font,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));


        return table;
    }

    private PdfPCell createCel(String text,Font font,int alignment){
        PdfPCell pdfPCel = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text,font));
        pdfPCel.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
        return pdfPCel;
    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.