# How to align a Chunk Left and Right Side

Tags: itext

i want to align the `Chunk` Left and Right side. Also the each `Chunk` have different format you can see in image.

i try the below code:

```
Chunk invoiceid = new Chunk("Invoice ID: ", font9BoldDARK_GRAY);
Chunk invoiceidvalue = new Chunk("value from database", font10NoramlBlack);
Chunk inoicdate = new Chunk("Invoice Date: ", font9BoldDARK_GRAY);
Chunk inoicedatevalue = new Chunk(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy").format(new Date()), font10NoramlBlack);// get From database

    Paragraph invoiceParagraph = new Paragraph();
    invoiceParagraph.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(325f));
    invoiceParagraph.add(invoiceid);
    invoiceParagraph.add(invoiceidvalue);

    invoiceParagraph1.add(Chunk.TABBING);

    invoiceParagraph1.add(inoicdate1);
    invoiceParagraph1.add(inoicedatevalue1);
    invoiceParagraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    pdfdocument.add(invoiceParagraph1);
```

which gives me result [image: here the my output] the Right side `Chunk` not in well format.

but i want align the like [image: required result] 
can you please help me.

Comment: Are you using an old version of iText on purpose? Or were you unaware that iText 7 has been released about a year and a half ago?

Comment: Also, if you insist on using iText 5, why aren't you reading the section about tabs and separators in [chapter 2](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/c/5c637ac-79b4-4abe-bbed-8c72ef6a0c61/samplechapter2.pdf) of the iText 5 documentation? The result that you show **is doing exactly what you ask in your code!** You want a tab at position `325`, and that's where the text starts. That makes your question very awkward. To me, it sounds as: I'm trying to add one and one like this `1 + 1`, but the result I get is `2`, and I want the result to be `3`. That's a weird question, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this, is to use iText 7. Read [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3) of the building blocks tutorial to discover how to create a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

The code to achieve this, is amazingly simple:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    // create a low-level document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    // create a high-level document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    // create a TabStop array
    List<TabStop> tabstops = new ArrayList<TabStop>();
    // don't forget to make a tab stop that aligns to the right
    tabstops.add(new TabStop(325, TabAlignment.RIGHT));
    // add paragraphs with Tab objects to the high-level document
    document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabstops)
            .add("Text to the left").add(new Tab()).add("Text to the right"));
    document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabstops)
            .add("ABCD").add(new Tab()).add("EFGH"));
    document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabstops)
            .add("01234").add(new Tab()).add("56789"));
    document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabstops)
            .add("iText 5 is old").add(new Tab()).add("iText 7 is new"));
    // close the document
    document.close();
}
```

Before you say *I don't recognize that code*, let me tell you that you are right: iText was completely rewritten. The code is now more intuitive to create, and easier to read.

**Update:** you are using the old iText 5 version that is no longer supported for free users (only for paying customers). As explained in the 2009 book "iText in Action - Second Edition", you created `glue` like this:

```
Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark())
```

You then used this glue in a `Paragraph` like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add("Text to the left");
p.add(glue);
p.add("Text to the right");
```

This way, you can indeed avoid having to use tabs in iText 5.

Comment: thanx for your answer..i am using 5.5.12 itext verstion..as you say iText 5 is not free also i read about AGPL

Comment: is itext 7 free? or should possible use iText 2.1.7 (java) It was released under MPL / LGPL

Comment: also i solve my problem using `Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark())` instead of using TAB

Comment: i just want create on page pdf nothing more ..that why i am asking which version should i so it will be free for me

Comment: Please read the blog post [How can I use iText for free?](https://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free) Versions prior to iText 5 [can not be used](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). Whether you can use iText 5 or 7 *for free* doesn't depend on the version, but on how you use it. For instance: you can't use any version in closed source, proprietary software that you distribute to your customers.

Answer (score -1):

this work for me:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("some Text");
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```